# Alignment of planets that orbit at same speed

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, outer-space

How could I calculate the alignment of 3 planets that orbit around the sun at the same speed? I have this data:

- P1: Distance from the sun 1000km and angular velocity 1 degree per day.
- P2: Distance from the sun 5000km and angular velocity 3 degree per day.
- P3: Distance from the sun 9000km and angular velocity 5 degree per day.

What about if need to know if they alignment to sun too?

Comment: This sounds like a question for [math.se] or [physics.se] rather than Puzzling.

Comment: Not necessarily. Angular velocity is proportional to √(r³), so this is not physics. I'm inclined to think that it's more geometry or (*gasp*) numerical simulation. So I agree that it doesn't have a puzzle feel. But it's just possible that there's a puzzly trick to it...